# converting a for loop to array filter

Tags: javascript, arrays

This javascript code tries to use the `array.filter` for better performance instead of the for loop "I guess".  Any way, the results are not the same, when it was expected to be. 
It tries to find out the names of `students` who are included in the `searchWords` array.
Any ideas why?thx

```js
let searchWords = ['john','matt','marry'];
let students = ['matt','jack'];
let names = [];
for (let i = 0; i < searchWords.length; i++) {
   if (students.indexOf(searchWords[i]) !== -1) {
       names.push(searchWords[i]);
   }
}
console.log(names.length); // => 1 "correct"

names = [];
names = searchWords.filter(x => students.filter(y => students.indexOf(x) !== -1));
console.log(names.length); // => 3 "incorrect"
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The filter line has essentially added another loop. It should be

```
names = searchWords.filter(x => students.indexOf(x) !== -1);
```

Comment: I was just answering that… ;-)

Comment: Wow javascript has changed since I last used it. Now we have `let` and lambda functions. Cool.

Comment: @0x499602D2—it always had lambda functions, the arrow syntax is new though (it sets *this* lexically rather than in the call).